# Article about Amazon Speaker being used for donations

Tags: grammar, syntax

I'm reading this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011556561000/k10011556561000.html) on how Amazon allowed their speaker to be used to donate to Japan's Red Cross. In the final sentence they get a quote from a Red Cross member, but I cannot make sense of the word **楽しみながら** and the pairing of the word **ほしい**

I know ~ながら means while doing a verb and that ほしい is to express a want or desire. Also I believe ほしい can only be used to express one's own wants/desires. So I am not sure of my translation.

> 日本赤十字社の人は「今まで寄付をしたことがない人も、**楽しみながら**寄付をしてほしいです」と話しています。
>
> My Translation: A member of Japan's Red Cross Society said "People who could not donate until now can also enjoy while wanting to donate"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption that ほしい can only be used to express your own desires is the problem here.

> Verb in て-form + ほしい = Want someone to do verb

The person you want to do the verb (if they are mentioned) is marked by に, e.g.

> 私はゆきさんに日本語を教えてほしい。
>   I want Yuki to teach me Japanese.

Your sentence:

> 今まで寄付をしたことがない人も、楽しみながら寄付をしてほしいです
>   We want even people who've never donated before to have fun making a donation.

Note that the people they want to do action are not marked by に here because they have been promoted to the topic of the sentence (but with は replaced by も).

Comment: I would suggest "...make a donation and enjoy doing it" or at least "and have fun doing it" for 楽しみながら. It sounds too much like they are doing something unrelated that's fun and making a donation at the same time.

Comment: Fair point. Is it better now?